# JavaScript from John Resig Learning Advanced JavaScript #45

Tags: javascript

```
function highest(){ 
          return makeArray(arguments).sort(function(a,b){ 
            return b - a; 
          }); 
        } 

function makeArray(array){ 
  return Array().slice.call( array ); 
} 

assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 4, "Verify the results.");
```

This example is #45 from John Resig`s Learning Advanced JavaScript. http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#45

Here are some questions which I would appreciate some help with. Thanks in advance.

1).  when `function highest()` returns `makeArray(arguments)`, does `function makeArray` take place before the `sort` function in `function highest`? So that after makeArray() runs, the remaining part

```
sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a;
```

of function highest continues and the sort takes place on the Array returned from makeArray?

2) In function makeArray(array), what exactly is "call" calling?

3) In function makeArray, is slice used because call takes its arguments separately rather than as an array?

4) In the final assert, does the [1] represent the location in an array of the 4 > i.e. after the sort there is an array ['5','4','3','3','2','1']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, that's exactly right. These actions happen in sequence.
2. It's calling `Array.prototype.slice` and passing  `array` which is the `arguments` object of `highest`. When called with no arguments, `slice` simply returns a copy the object it's working on. This is how we convert the array-like `arguments` object to an actual array.
3. See #2. `slice` and `call` are used in tandem to produce a copy of `arguments` that's an actual array.
4. Yes, again, you're correct. The `highest` function returns an array containing its arguments sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

As I was answering this, another answer was posted.  But I think that most of the confusion shown in the question comes down to one key point.

In JavaScript, functions and methods are objects.  Which may have properties, etc.  When you say `Array.slice` you get the `slice` method.  When you say `Array.slice()` you now are *calling* the `slice` method.  So `Array.slice.call` accesses the `call` property of the `slice` method on the `Array` object.  (That property happens to be a method in its own right.)  And `Array.slice.call( stuff )` calls *that*.

That's a pretty fundamental fact of the language which is easy to miss.  But if you don't understand that point, you'll find code that uses it virtually impossible to actually understand.